# Custom CLI command in PhpStorm

Tags: command-line-interface, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm. I want to make custom CLI command and then assign shortcuts to them.

For example, I want enter `branch` and run `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to get current git branch.

How can I do it in PhpStorm?

Comment: To run some external app on shortcut? External Tools -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-third-party-tools.html. Once created you can assign a shortcut to it at Keymap (it has a node for External Tools): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html

Comment: If you want to run that in your Terminal though ... why not make an alias in your shell: bash/powershell/whatever